# Changing Datetime Format in Python

Tags: python, datetime

how do I change format to DD/M/YYY H:M for this line:

```
ax1.set_title('from {} to {} \n'.format(startTime, endTime, fontsize=22))
```

cause currently when I run the module it is displayed this way: YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S

This is my code:

```
linematchregex = re.compile('(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+),(\d+\.\d+)')

startTime = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter start time :'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
endTime   = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter end time :') , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')


**ax1.set_title('from {} to {} \n'.format(startTime, endTime, fontsize=22))**
ax1.set_ylabel('Temp')
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please consolidate your sample code. The plotting is unrelated to your question.

Comment: hi Kay, I have reduce my code, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `strftime()` (sort of the inverse of `strptime()` which you already use): https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: @backtotheroots3 why don't you give it a go and see where you get to?

Comment: ok I will, sorry because I do not have my program with me right now

Comment: Hi john, I already use strftime for sometime else as you have said, so will it cause problems if I use it again?

Comment: I tried inserting this ax1.set_title('from {} to {} \n'.format(startTime, endTime, datetime.strptime('%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M') but I get a error - strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments

Comment: Read my answer again carefully, then read the strftime docs carefully.  It's all right here, but you're not using it correctly.